# HTML/CSS div styling overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, styling

I have a div with 0 height, but the text is not cutoff, only the div box.
Example:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:10px;background-color:red;">
Text
</div>
```

I want it to cutoff the text to not overflow out of the div.

This is what it looks like:

[image: *image1*]

And this is what I want it to look like:

[image: image2]

Comment: what happens if you use `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: @Dips it must be the answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the main div

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `overflow:hidden;`

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/v4ykN/

This is a good overview of the `overflow` property: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/ with some good info to remember:

> bear in mind that content that is hidden in this way is utterly
>   inaccessible (short of viewing the source). So for example a user has
>   their default font size set larger than you would expect, you may be
>   pushing text outside of a box and hiding it completely from their
>   view.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use Overflow:hidden in css
 Refer this example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Answer (score 0):

You must use `overflow:hidden;` Good luck with what you are doing

Comment: This answer has already been posted numerous times. You do not add anything of value with this answer.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, i'm very new to this website, wont happen again :)